# Replacing multiple "" from polybase string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in which one of the columns is Error. Most of the cases the column has no value, but in some case it do get a value.

When I use to_csv on it that column is like

```
Country,Etl_Batch,Input_Date,Input_CampaignID,Tags,TargetGroupID,CampaignType,Duration,LeadTime,Notes,IsMultiChannel,IsRecurrence,Status,Error,Api_Executed_Datetime
RO,1511293247,2019-07-02,4177,,89,No Control,1,0,,False,True,Successful,,2019-07-16 15:26:00.696304
RO,1511293247,2019-07-02,4178,,232,Test/Control,3,0,,False,False,Successful,"Exception caught at HTTPHelper postXMLHTTPSRequest. Http response: &lt;?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?&gt;&lt;error&gt;&lt;code&gt;UMS-105&lt;/code&gt;&lt;description&gt;'activities' is not specified or invalid&lt;/description&gt;&lt;severity&gt;ERROR&lt;/severity&gt;&lt;/error&gt;&#x0D;Error message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ",2019-07-16 15:26:00.696304
RO,1511293247,2019-07-02,4179,,-1,Test/Control,3,0,,False,False,Successful,,2019-07-16 15:26:00.696304
```

When I create an external table using this data I get a polybase error.

As it has got text like

```
"Exception caught at HTTPHelper postXMLHTTPSRequest. Http response: &lt;?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?&gt;&lt;error&gt;&lt;code&gt;UMS-105&lt;/code&gt;&lt;description&gt;'activities' is not specified or invalid&lt;/description&gt;&lt;severity&gt;ERROR&lt;/severity&gt;&lt;/error&gt;&#x0D;Error message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. "
```

This is a single string but since it has got `""` (2 double quotes in between), it causes an error.

I have to remove `'""'` (2 double quotes) from within the string in python. How do I do that?

Comment: do you want to replace '""' with " ?

Comment: yes I have replace those double quotes with a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
def app(row):
    return str(row['Error']).replace("\"\""," ")

df['Error'] = df.apply(lambda x: app(x),axis = 1)
print(df['Error'])
```

Comment: what error did it give? Or did it not produce the expected result? @AmanKhandelwal

Comment: didn't produced any result

Comment: check your dataframe, the column named with `Error` will be fixed on the way you want, to see the results output check my updated answer.

Comment: ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
It is giving this error. Any idea about the cause

Answer (score 0):

you can replace "" with " like this:

```
yourString = "encoding=\"\"UTF-8\"\""
print(yourString)
yourString = yourString.replace("\"\"", "\"")
print(yourString)
```

output:

```
encoding=""UTF-8""
encoding="UTF-8"
```

Comment: It is a dataframe...I tried this thing much before. 
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'
This error occurs when I use this

Comment: the data type is float64 ?